# Выравнивание блоков по ширине (%) - justify

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте.
Задача:
Родительский элемент с резиновой шириной (width: 94%, width: 96% и подобные варианты).
Внутри блоки с фиксированной шириной (width: 120px или 180px или иной размер). Количество этих блоков не фиксировано, может быть от 1 и до бесконечности.

Задача: выровнять по текущей ширине родительского элемента justify.

На чистом CSS такое не сделать, поэтому перешли к js (jquery). Единственное, что удалось найти:

```js
  $(function ()
  {
    changeMargin();
  });
  $(window).resize(function()
  {
    changeMargin();
  });
  function changeMargin()
  {
    var container_width = $('div.list').width();
    var item_width = $('div.item').width();
    var items_count = Math.floor(container_width / item_width);
    var items_width = item_width * items_count;
    var difference = container_width - items_width;
    var margin = difference / (items_count - 1);
    $('div.item').each(function(index)
    {
      if (index > 0 && index % items_count != 0)
        $(this).css('margin-left', margin+'px');
      else
        $(this).css('margin-left', '0px');
    });
  }
```

```css
.list {
  width: 95%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  }
.item {
  width: 163px;
  height: 110px;
  float: left;
  background: #ff0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list">
  <div class="item">Content</div>
  <div class="item">Content</div>
  <div class="item">Content</div>
  <div class="item">Content</div>
  <div class="item">Content</div>
  <div class="item">Content</div>
</div>
```

Но есть две проблемы:
1. Если элементов не хватает даже чтобы заполнить первую и единственную строчку, то блоки слипаются. - надо в таких случаях всё равно добавлять отступ, хотя бы 10px
2. На маленьких экранах почему-то структура нарушается совсем, т.е. скрипт криво определяет, где последний элемент в строке, и на новой строке получается два элемента слипаются.

Тут тоже всё сломалось... Подскажите, может есть варианты правильнее реализовать автоматический подбор отступа?

[image: выравнивание]

Пояснительная картинка.
Предположим, что ширина блоков задана в стилях (так оно и есть) и равна 180px. В зависимости от ширины экрана скрипт высчитывает, сколько может поместиться и подбирает отступ для всех элементов (кроме первого, если используется margin-left, или последнего, если используется margin-right). При этом отступ не должен быть меньше 5px. Если не помещается, то блок переносится на след строку.
Ширина родительского элемента не резиновая.
Также, у блоков тоже несколько вариантов ширины (для адаптивности) - все размеры прописаны в стилях под нужные разрешения экранов. Т.е. ширину блока в самом скрипте прописывать жестко нельзя.

Comment: `выровнять по текущей ширине родительского элемента` КАК?

Comment: @Jean-Claude то есть как? justify - по ширине строки.

Comment: так они итак без скриптов так заполняются, учите селекторы css

Comment: @Jean-Claude
ничего подобного.
по умолчанию можно выровнять по левому или правому краю или по центру, но никак не растянуть имеющиеся блоки на всю ширину строки родительского элемента, подбирая автоматически значения margin-left или margin-right, при этом обнуляя отступ последнего блока в строке.
Есть методики применения justify (чистый css), но они подходят только, если количество блоков заведомо известно. + проблема с последней строкой, а свойство text-align-last совсем не кроссбраузерно. Поэтому решение только в js

Comment: короче хрен поймешь как выравнивать, нарисуй макет результата.

Comment: @Jean-Claude обновил пост, добавил рисунок и коммент к нему, не знаю как еще подробнее написать.

Comment: Flexbox с задачей справляется без особых проблем. Надо только чуток подрихтовать под кокретные отступы http://codepen.io/alexeyten/full/mVPVJw/

Comment: @AlexeyTen справедливости ради у вас если убрать `.item-stub` то нихрена не справляется, костыль ради костыля)))

Comment: Он гораздо проще и понятнее, чем куча непонятных вычислений.

Comment: флекс хорош, но есть одно НО, насколько я знаю работает в ie10+, для 9 версии надо делать костыли в стилях и то не факт, что всегда помогут. На живом сайте, мне кажется, лучше такой небольшой js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема слипания следующая - ширина элемента возвращается целым числом, округленным в большую сторону, поэтому ширину вычисляем при помощи getBoundingClientRect()

Пробую решить так, все работает:

```js
$(function() {
  changeMargin();

  $(window).resize(function() {
    changeMargin();
  });

  function changeMargin() {
    var container_width = Math.floor($('div.list')[0].getBoundingClientRect().width);
    var item_width = $('div.item').width();
    var items_count = Math.floor(container_width / item_width);
    var items_width = item_width * items_count;
    var difference = container_width - items_width;
    var margin = Math.floor(difference / (items_count - 1));

    if (margin < 10) {
      items_count -= 1;
      var items_width = item_width * items_count;
      var difference = container_width - items_width;
      var margin = Math.floor(difference / (items_count - 1));
    }

    $('div.item').each(function(index, el) {
      if ((index > 0) && (index % items_count != 0)) {
        $(this).css('margin-left', margin + 'px');
      } else {
        $(this).css('margin-left', '0');
      }
    });
  }
});
```

```css
.list {
  width: 95%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.item {
  width: 163px;
  height: 110px;
  float: left;
  background: #ff0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list">
  <div class="item">Content</div>
  <div class="item">Content</div>
  <div class="item">Content</div>
  <div class="item">Content</div>
  <div class="item">Content</div>
  <div class="item">Content</div>
  <div class="item">Content</div>
  <div class="item">Content</div>
  <div class="item">Content</div>
  <div class="item">Content</div>
  <div class="item">Content</div>
</div>
```

**Пример 2**: функция оформлена как плагин jquery

```js
$(function() {

  $.fn.flex = function() {
    var element = $(this);
    var container_width = Math.floor(element[0].getBoundingClientRect().width);
    var item_width = element.find('.item').width();
    var items_count = Math.floor(container_width / item_width);
    var items_width = item_width * items_count;
    var difference = container_width - items_width;
    var margin = Math.floor(difference / (items_count - 1));

    if (margin < 10) {
      items_count -= 1;
      var items_width = item_width * items_count;
      var difference = container_width - items_width;
      var margin = Math.floor(difference / (items_count - 1));
    }

    element.each(function(index, el) {
      $(el).find('.item').each(function(index, el) {
        if ((index > 0) && (index % items_count != 0)) {
          $(this).css('margin-left', margin + 'px');
        } else {
          $(this).css('margin-left', '0');
        }
      });
    });
  }

  $('div.list').flex();
  $(window).resize(function() {
    $('div.list').flex();
  });
});
```

```css
.list {
  width: 95%;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.item {
  width: 163px;
  height: 110px;
  float: left;
  background: #ff0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.list:nth-of-type(even) .item {
  background-color: #cd4236;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list">
  <div class="item">Content</div>
  <div class="item">Content</div>
  <div class="item">Content</div>
  <div class="item">Content</div>
  <div class="item">Content</div>
  <div class="item">Content</div>
  <div class="item">Content</div>
  <div class="item">Content</div>
  <div class="item">Content</div>
  <div class="item">Content</div>
  <div class="item">Content</div>
</div>

<div class="list">
  <div class="item">Content</div>
  <div class="item">Content</div>
  <div class="item">Content</div>
  <div class="item">Content</div>
  <div class="item">Content</div>
  <div class="item">Content</div>
  <div class="item">Content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо, теперь проблема со слипанием решена. вопрос только: условие если отступ меньше 10, то выполняется перенос или if (margin < 10) {
выполняется перенос, я правильно понял?

Comment: @Aaron это просто защита от маленьких границ, например 1-2 пикселя, да. получается на 1 блок в рядке меньше.

Comment: отлично, ещё раз благодарю)

Comment: @Aaron добавил пример 2 - оформил как jquery плагин.

Comment: я правильно понимаю, что вариант плагина даёт возможность использовать данное решение сразу для нескольких контейнеров, содержащих одинаковый класс без дублирования всего кода?
ещё какие-то различия имеются: скорость, ресурсы или что-то ещё?

Comment: можно подправить вариант плагина так, чтобы использовать для нескольких блоков. Дело в том, что есть два родительских блока, внутри которых выравниваются эти элементы. Но ширина у элементов в первом блоке отличается от ширины во втором. А плагин лепит для всех элементов на странице один и тот же отступ

Comment: @Aaron each() перенести  сразу после объявления  var element

Comment: честно не понял как, я в конце дописал $('div.list').flex(), $('div.list-two').flex()
работать работает, но почему-то на странице, где нет этих блоков появляется ошибка
TypeError: element[0] is undefined
var container_width = Math.floor(element[0].getBoundingClientRect().width);